# ACS - A valid option to manage users

Tags: azure, azure-acs

I'm developing an Windows Azure web application and I would like to understand if I should use Windows Azure Control Service (ACS) in my Architecture or not. So, my questions are:

1. Is the Windows Azure Control Service (ACS) a valid option to manage users?
2. I mean, should I consider it as an "Authentication System" for my application instead of implement my own database (using Membership for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well "valid" as in it works and is supported, yes! But I'd say the value is more as a way to map identities and claims presented from other identity providers - like Live, Google, etc. - to claims for your application to respond to.

You can certainly set up your own users via the ACS portal, but for a true membership system you want the user to be able to change passwords, profile information, etc.  Much of that can be accomplished via the [ACS Management REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee706703.aspx) but I don't know of any higher level abstractions or framework that you might be able to leverage.  It seems like it would be a LOT of work that isn't really a core part of your application.